# Ellipse position according to grid layout

Tags: c#, xaml, responsive-design, windows-phone-8.1, ellipse

I'm facing some elements' positioning problem in my wp 8.1 app (XAML/C#). I've read that to create a flexible layout, I should use the grid control. 
Well, here is my XAML within the page element:

```
<Grid  Style="{StaticResource LayoutGridCreateProfilStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Height="60" Fill="#F3A8E4F9" ></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Height="40" Fill="Gray"></Rectangle>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Height="420" Background="Transparent"/>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="3">
        <Ellipse Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="100" Fill="Black" Canvas.Left="152" Canvas.Top="10"></Ellipse>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

In the XAML designer, I'm actually seeing what I want and it looks like below:

[image: Designer Picture]

And here is how it looks like on my Nokia Lumia 925:

[image: Lumia 925 Picture]

As you can see, the ellipse is cut and I really cannot figure out how to place it as it should be and actually appears in the designer view.
Maybe somebody could help me with that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are running out of height to show all the elements of your grid. The first three rows take up an accumulated height of 540 pixels. If the run time height available if 640 then you only have 100 left over for the last row of your grid.

But your Ellipse is offset 10 pixels from the top of the Canvas and so it needs a total of 110 (10 offset + 100 pixel ellipse height) in order to show fully. If your last row has less than 110 pixels of space then it will be truncated, as indeed it seems to be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and indeed you're right. So I set the Canvas.Top property to 0 and it was still cut, a bit less but still. I had to reset the size of the ellipse the get it done. But how can I predict the size of the run time  height available ? How would you do to get it fixed for all screen sizes ?

Comment: You cannot predict the height because different phones have different heights. So instead make your last grid row to be Auto so it always has room for the ellipse and then set the second to last row as the * (star) sized so it has whatever room is left.